# mysql: insert rows from json object keys

Tags: mysql, json

I have an odd data structure (MongoDB origin) which I'm trying to migrate / break out into a separate table.

Each row contains a JSON Blob, like so:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "attributes": {
    "typeA": {
      "https://example.com/id/20413eba-23f4-4204-a504-e32b91d00e67" : {
        "_id": "20413eba-23f4-4204-a504-e32b91d00e67",
        "created": 1707846236,
        "content": "Example!",
      },
      "https://example.com/id/f20e9118556b8f7a161141cc3d6072d6" : {
        "_id": "f20e9118556b8f7a161141cc3d6072d6",
        "created": 1708455800,
        "content": "Surprise!",
      },
    }
  }
}
```

There are various `types` within `attributes`, and each type contains various items, which I want to transform into a new row in another table.

I can access all the properties via `SELECT` with `JSON_EXTRACT`:

```
SELECT 
  JSON_KEYS(
    JSON_UNQUOTE(`contents`), 
    "$.attributes"
  ) as attributes 
  FROM `entities` 
  WHERE JSON_CONTAINS_PATH(
    JSON_UNQUOTE(`contents`), 
    'all', 
    "$.attributes"
);
```

Except I'm not quite groking how to build this looping query so that each child node of a type becomes the basis for an `INSERT`.

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
table : comments
+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------------+-------------+
|        _id      |     type   |   created  |        url         |   content   |
+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------------+-------------+
| "20413eba-..."  | "Type A"   | 1707846236 | "...20413eba-..."  | "Example!"  |
| "f20e91185..."  | "Type A"   | 1708455800 | "...f20e91185..."  | "Surprise!" |
```

**EDIT**: It seems, that I need to do this as a Stored Procedure, any help appreciated.

Comment: what are the columns for the other table? what version of mysql, specifically does it support `JSON_TABLE` function?

Comment: Provide complete sample and desired final data state according to [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3.

Comment: *Each row contains a JSON Blob, like so* This is not valid JSON value from MySQL looking point.

Comment: @Akina correct. This JSON blob structure originates from MongoDB and predates MySQL JSON methods, the field is technically `longblob`.

Comment: @ITgoldman `Server version: 10.4.28-MariaDB`, `Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 8.2.4 `, When I try basic `JSON_TABLE` example from the manual, I get the following error: 
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use

Comment: ‍♂️ just realized JSON_TABLE support wasn't added until 10.6 https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_table-support/, looks like I need to upgrade

Comment: yes. i don't think there is a simple way to do that using standard sql (unless using some crazy string manipulations). so that leaves stored procedure, or use a scripting language. upgrading might be risky.

Comment: @ITgoldman thanks I'll look into Stored Procedures